# $\mathbb{P}(X \leq Y)$ only knowing law of X and Y?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be to random variables.
We suppose X and Y follow the same probability law given for all k (strictly) positive integer ,
$$\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\frac{\muˆ{k}- \lambdaˆk}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{1}{2^k}$$
Where $\mu=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$ and  $\lambda=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}$
We suppose they are NOT independant, and that we don’t have other informations.
Is it possible to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X \leq Y)$ , and if yes, how ?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: I suspect you can get any value between $\frac18$ and $1$